# Threading Task оптимизация

Tags: c#, асинхронность, task

Задача: при инициализации комнаты, в которой есть только 2 игрока, запускается задача, с методом, который описан ниже. Это тик обновления. Нужно вызывать обновление у двух игроков, при этом чтобы один не ожидал другого. В обновлениях могут быть долгие операции, такие как расчет скорости атаки и т д.

Правильно ли я реализовал подобный метод? Что будет слышно по оптимизации, когда таких комнат будет 10 тысяч?

```
private async Task InternalTick()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < _queueModels.Count; iterator++)
            Task.Run(async () => await _queueModels[iterator].TickAsync());

        await Task.Delay(_timeUpdateOneFrameInTheMap, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Task.Run лишний

Comment: @aepot Есть способ избежать чтобы одна итерация ждала следующую?

Comment: @Alexey вызвать метод без `await`, сохранить таски в массив, а потом использовать `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten не выход. Внутри тиков есть отправка пакетов через await. Это обязательно

Comment: у вас переменная iterator  общая на все задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так получистя

```
private async Task InternalTick()
{
    CancellationToken token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    int interval = _timeUpdateOneFrameInTheMap;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    while (true)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        await Task.WhenAll(_queueModels.Select(x => x.TickAsync()));
        int delay = interval - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (delay > 0)
            await Task.Delay(delay, token);
        else
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

Секундомер будет компенсировать время, затраченное на работу и вычитать его от общего промежутка времени. Простая математика.

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо!